# Redefining functions defined in standard libc header files?

Tags: gcc, header-files

Is there any `gcc` trick that lets me redefine the signature of `libc` functions (e.g. `fsetpos`) defined in standard headers (e.g. `stdio.h`)? As of now if I do that, I receive duplicate declaration error message.

Comment: Tell us why, so we understand why just declaring and defining e.g. `my_fsetpos` won't do?

Answer (score 0):

Declarations in standard headers are decorated with many additional attributes to help optimizations, improve portability, etc. (and sometimes even defined as macros). If your declaration is even slightly incompatible to those you are guaranteed to get many interesting messages from compiler.

So if you try to overload some standard function, do not include standard headers in its file.